# jQuery add variable before setting plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

What is the best way to add a variable to this structure before setting plugin options?

```
$('.example').somePlugin({
     option1: 1, 
     option2: 2
});
```

More details: Where can I add `var selector = $(this)` to use in the callback? I have to use the `$('.example')` selector in the callback.

```
$('.example').somePlugin({
    option1: 1, 
    option2: 2,
    callback: function () {
      // use variable selector
    }
 });
```

Comment: What is referenced by `$(this)`?

Comment: why not catching that in the `somePlugin` function?

Comment: same: why not in `somePlugin`? Otherwise you need to wrap the plugin in to another jQuery extension and put the assignment there.

Comment: Or, if you have access to the options of the plugin within the callback, just add another option to the parameter basket like `... option3: $(this), ...`

Comment: I don't think this is possible: `somePlugin` is responsible to set the context for `this` in the callback.

Comment: my mistake.. yes i'm trying to add it in somePlugin

Comment: @AxelAmthor I meant to say somePlugin not selector. Sorry my mistake. How can I add the var in somePlugin? before the options and callback

Answer (score 0):

One option is to loop through items and initialise the plugin on each instance, as follows:

```
$('.example').each(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.somePlugin({
        option1: 1, 
        option2: 2,
        callback: function () {
          // I can use $self/$(this) for this callback now 

        }
    });
});
```

That way `$(this)` is a reference to a unique instance and is available to you for the callback